# Building custom TextBlock control in WPF

Tags: wpf, render, textblock

I have built custom WPF Control which unique function is displaying text. 
 I tried using `TextBlock` from `System.Windows.Controls` namespace but it's not working for me (I have ~10000 strings with different position and too much memory loss). 
 So I tried making my own control by inheriting FrameworkElement, overriding `OnRender` method which now contain single line:

```
drawingContext.DrawText(...);
```

But...
I get a little confusing result.
After comparing performance for 10000 objects, I realized that the time needed for creating and adding to Canvas is still ~10 sec, and memory usage for my application raises from ~32MB to ~60MB !!! 
So no benefits at all.

Can anyone explain why this happens, and what is the other way to create simple (simple = allocate less memory, take less time to create) visual with two functions:

1. display text
2. set position (using thickness or `TranslateTransform`)

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please post code of what you are exactly doing? Also its not quite clear why `TextBlock` is not helping you? Did yo explore readonly `RichTextBox`? `FlowDocument` for complex layout texts? I do agree with @John about StringBuilder.

Comment: TextBlock is helping me but takes too much memory because of near 10000 TextBlocks, and i need that much beacuse every one of them have different position.

Comment: Don't take me wrong, maybe all control's appearance can be modified using styles but i have never tried. So i want ask another question:
Can I get this appearance if i apply style to Button? [Media Player Controls](http://i41.tinypic.com/j90glt.png) ps. buttons on the picture are made by combining several Ellipses and Paths.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code (a little bit modified):

```
public class SimpleTextBlock : FrameworkElement
{
    #region Static

    private const double _fontSize = 12;
    private static Point _emptyPoint;
    private static Typeface _typeface;
    private static LinearGradientBrush _textBrush;

    public readonly static DependencyProperty TextWidthProperty;

    static SimpleTextBlock()
    {
        _emptyPoint = new Point();
        _typeface = new Typeface(new FontFamily("Sergoe UI"), FontStyles.Normal, FontWeights.Normal, FontStretches.Normal);

        GradientStopCollection GSC = new GradientStopCollection(2);
        GSC.Add(new GradientStop(Color.FromArgb(160, 255, 255, 255), 0.0));
        GSC.Add(new GradientStop(Color.FromArgb(160, 180, 200, 255), 0.7));
        _textBrush = new LinearGradientBrush(GSC, 90);
        _textBrush.Freeze();


        SimpleTextBlock.TextWidthProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "TextWidth",
            typeof(double),
            typeof(SimpleTextBlock),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0.0d, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));
    }

    #endregion

    FormattedText _formattedText;

    public SimpleTextBlock(string text)
    {
        _formattedText = new FormattedText(text, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, FlowDirection.LeftToRight, _typeface, _fontSize, _textBrush);
    }

    public SimpleTextBlock(string text, FlowDirection FlowDirection)
    {
        _formattedText = new FormattedText(text, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, FlowDirection, _typeface, _fontSize, _textBrush);
    }

    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        _formattedText.MaxTextWidth = (double)GetValue(TextWidthProperty);
        drawingContext.DrawText(_formattedText, _emptyPoint);
    }

    public double TextWidth
    {
        get { return (double)base.GetValue(TextWidthProperty); }
        set { base.SetValue(TextWidthProperty, value); }
    }

    public double ActualTextWidth
    {
        get { return _formattedText.Width; }
    }

    public double ActualTextHeight
    {
        get { return _formattedText.Height; }
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code is good to have, I think people (including myself) were wondering why you need 10,000 textblocks in a single view. It seems like there is a fundamental problem with how the page is being layed out. Have you looked at [`FlowDocuments`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970909.aspx)? Could you maybe attach a screen shot or drawing of what the program looks like so we could help you figure out the best course of action

Comment: I don't have SS yet, but i want to make media library with search, something like library in WindowsMediaPlayer. I don't know anything about FlowDocuments, but I intend to look at it.

Comment: Why not use a stylized `ListBox` or `DataGrid`?

Comment: I used ListBox but it looks so poor and i'm not familiar with stylizing any component, so i build my own one. I think it's easier to make my own control which i can modify at any time than learn how to use one that already exist. Can you post me any code which explain how to use styles? Stylized ListBox will be good as any.

Answer (score 1):

Since it sounds like we determined you should stylize a control like listbox, here are some examples of different things you can do:

[Use Images as Items](http://richapps.wordpress.com/2009/02/11/listboxstyle/)

[Stylized and Binding](http://www.davesquared.net/2010/03/wpf-newbie-styles-listbox.html)

Honestly it all depends on what you want it to look like. WPF is great in how much control it gives you on how something looks.

[Crazy example using a listbox to make the planet's orbits](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=40)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [AvalonEdit](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/AvalonEdit.aspx)

Also not sure how you are storing the strings, but have you used `StringBuilder` before?

Comment: Check the code i posted.
I'm not sure how would StringBuilder help?